# Power the Raspberry Pi via the 5v Pin

Tags: gpio, hardware, power

I tried to power my Raspberry Pi via the GPIO header, but it didn't work.
I powered it with exactly 5v, but it won't boot, but the Status LED "ACT" is on. It's darker then normal, but it's on. I think the Raspberry is OK, because if I power it via USB, everything's fine.I wonder about that, because I read it's directly connected to the 5v Logic, so it must be connected to the Micro-USB. But if this was the case, it would work, would't it?

By the way: I double-checked the connections to the Pins, they're OK.

Comment: Are you using the same power supply in both cases? Have you MEASURED the voltage? What is the voltage at TP1 & TP2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ACT LED is dim, it means the Pi isn't getting enough current. The USB cable supplies on average, around 500 mA which is just enough to get things going. You may remember that a 700 mA power supply is recommended by the foundation. I suspect your power source is down around 300 mA or lower, causing the problems. Like @Milliways said, if you measure the voltage you'll probably see an appreciable drop because there isn't enough current in your power supply. Beef it up and you should be OK.